# Why my app.config do not contain connectionString (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration, connection-string

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

there is no connection string so i cant use my database please help me !

Comment: you will need to add your connection string to it

Comment: why don't you enter your connection string into `app.config`? That way you'll have `connectionString` in your `app.config`

Comment: The easiest way is to go to the Project Properties, Settings and create a new setting fo type `Connection String`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it, as showed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <-- EXAMPLE -->
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-fefdc1f0-bd81-4ce9-b712-93a062e01031;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-fefdc1f0-bd81-4ce9-b712-93a062e01031.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, i was watching a Tutorial but he never explained that because is App.config was already done.

Comment: @B.Nahil this is covered in all courses and tutorials, and there are a lot of duplicates too. You can create a connection string from the Settings page in the Project Properties.